# Find node references in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I have created a very basic game with SceneKit and the view editor. I have created a `pawn` and I added two copies of this node in the scene, so I have two references of the `pawn`.

I got my first reference like this:

```swift
pawnNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: OBJECTS.PAWN, recursively: true)!
```

and I was expecting to be able to access the other reference (that has the same name) like this:

```
secondReference = scene.rootNode.childNodes.filter({ $0.name == OBJECTS.PAWN })
```

but frankly the latter returns `[]` and I can't access childNodes with the same name.

I have temporarily targeted the reference with a dirty `secondReference = scene.rootNode.childNodes[3]` but I would like to do this properly.

Comment: How about adding something like `var pawnNodes: Set<SCNNode> = []` to your SCNScene, and then when you create a node you add it to the set? Then you can get the nodes with a certain name or whatever you need.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's an option, but I would like to know how to target childNodes with the same name, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I think you could call `enumerateChildNodes(withName:using:)`, but you would most likely have to do it recursively. It seems like the Set would be a much better solution, and more efficient as well.

Comment: Or try and get the parent of all the nodes with the same name, and then run that second chunk of code where you use `filter`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing with `rootNode.childNodes.filter({ $0.name == someName })` but the filter returns `[]`

Comment: So are all the pawn nodes at the highest level in the scene graph hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, here's the scene graph hierarchy:
https://i.ibb.co/dPSd0RL/Screenshot-2020-05-11-at-12-07-31.png